# openVPN lags with 2 (or more) clients

Tags: openvpn, lag, clients

I am running a openVPN-Server for some time now, and it works great.
On that server I created two new certificates via easy-rsa and formed it into two config-files for two new clients, like I always do.

Then I set up a Debian11 Client, that runs in a Virtual Machine. It has a static local IP and I configured it to connect to the openVPN-Server in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
  address 192.168.1.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  openvpn ovpnconfig_5.ovpn
```

Of course my openvpn-config file is located in /etc/openvpn/ovpnconfig_5.ovpn.config

Everything works fine. Now I cloned the VM and started the cloned Debian from another Host in the same network. I changed /etc/hostname, the IP-Address in /etc/network/interfaces to `192.168.1.7` and the `openvpn ovpnconfig_5.ovpn` to `openvpn ovpnconfig_7.ovpn`, which is the other ovpn-Config I created at first. I put this other ovpn-config into /etc/openvpn/

If I only run one VM at a time, it works great.
But if both VMs are running, the SSH connection to both clients lags. Like so: when one ssh-connection is smooth, the other hangs.
I assume, I forgot to change something at the cloned VM, so the server mixes them up. But the logs at the openVPN-Server report, that both clients with different Names in the config have been connected to different IP-Adresses, etc.

Any ideas, what I am missing?

Comment: Check the IP addresses and ethernet addresses are all different on both systems.

Comment: The ethernet address of the cloned system was the problem. Thank's for your input!
So, if you clone a VM, the MAC-Address is the same as the original system, and in my VM-Host the option to change the MAC-Address is a little bit hidden. Now it works great! 